# Customizing services and Triggers in Dynamics AX Retail?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I am not able to find examples or Information related to Customizing Services vs Customizing Triggers in AX 2012 Retail(POS). Can some one provide me the info with examples if possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On which version of AX 2012 (R2, R3) and on which POS (EPOS, MPOS)?

Comment: R2 version and anything(EPOS,MPOS) would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install RetailSDK from Microsoft Dynamics AX setup (Retail Components >> Retail SDK). It will create a folder called "Retail SDK" inside your Documents folder with plenty of examples of services and triggers inside the "POS Plug-ins" folder.

Comment: Ok I will check that. Thanks .